# Eclipse fails to deploy exploded ear on weblogic

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, weblogic, ear

I'm getting the following error:

```
####<2014-07-29 09:48:31 CEST> <Error> <Deployer> <PL-00032WS455> <pnb> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1406620111037> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1406620094715" for task "3". Error is: "weblogic.management.DeploymentException: "^M
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: ^M
        at weblogic.persistence.PersistenceDeployment$PersistenceDeploymentExtension.init(PersistenceDeployment.java:66)^M
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.CreateAppDeploymentExtensionsFlow.prepare(CreateAppDeploymentExtensionsFlow.java:44)^M
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:706)^M
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)^M
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:237)^M
        at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:61)^M
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:207)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:96)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:229)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)^M
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)^M
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)^M
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)^M
Caused By: weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentException: duplicate persistence units with name sbiu-pl in scope pnb-cti-ear. First PU location: file:/C:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/my_dom/servers/pnb/tmp/_WL_user/pnb-cti-ear/6rli5f/APP-INF/lib/solo-db-1.4.jar/. Second PU location: file:/C:/Users/m337951/workspace/TRUNK_ECLIPSE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/pnb-cti-ear/beadep/my_dom/pnb-cti-ear/APP-INF/lib/solo-db-1.4.jar/^M
        at weblogic.persistence.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.assertNoDuplicate(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:383)^M
        at weblogic.persistence.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.processDescriptor(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:362)^M
        at weblogic.persistence.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.loadPersistenceDescriptor(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:259)^M
        at weblogic.persistence.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.loadPersistenceDescriptors(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:118)^M
        at weblogic.persistence.EarPersistenceUnitRegistry.<init>(EarPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:52)^M
        at weblogic.persistence.PersistenceDeployment$PersistenceDeploymentExtension.init(PersistenceDeployment.java:62)^M
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.CreateAppDeploymentExtensionsFlow.prepare(CreateAppDeploymentExtensionsFlow.java:44)^M
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:706)^M
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)^M
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:237)^M
        at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:61)^M
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:207)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:96)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:229)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)^M
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)^M
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)^M
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)^M
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)^M
```

I started getting this error after switching weblogic to nonstaging mode and publishing mode to exploded ear. I want to keep this setting so that fastswap works, but I'm now unable to publish the module at all. It looks like eclipse is trying to publish one module twice, once in .metadata and the second time in weblogic domain folder. Why is that happening and how can I fix this. Publishing as a packaged ear works and publishing as an exploded ear without the use of eclipse also works (just console and exploded ear made by command line maven).

EDIT: I publish using servers tab in eclipse, by right clicking weblogic and selecting "publish" (and "clean" as well).

EDIT2: I found the following exception in logs occuring before the exception above. It looks like weblogic tries to remove the extra redundant package, but fails, which in turn sets the stage for the next exception to happen.

```
####<2014-07-29 12:14:08 CEST> <Warning> <Deployer> <PL-00032WS455> <pnb> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1406628848672> <BEA-149251> <Operation Remove failed for application "pnb-cti-ear". Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.remove(WebAppModule.java:851)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$4.previous(ModuleStateDriver.java:236)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$4.previous(ModuleStateDriver.java:223)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:148)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.remove(ModuleStateDriver.java:104)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.remove(ScopedModuleDriver.java:236)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.remove(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:154)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.remove(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:157)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$4.previous(ModuleStateDriver.java:236)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$4.previous(ModuleStateDriver.java:223)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:148)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.remove(ModuleStateDriver.java:104)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.remove(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:191)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$3.previous(BaseDeployment.java:758)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:148)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.remove(BaseDeployment.java:323)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.remove(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.remove(DeploymentStateChecker.java:216)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.remove(AppContainerInvoker.java:135)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.silentRemove(AbstractOperation.java:451)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCancel(ActivateOperation.java:132)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.silentCancelOnPrepareFailure(AbstractOperation.java:423)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:101)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:229)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.remove(WebAppModule.java:851)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$4.previous(ModuleStateDriver.java:236)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$4.previous(ModuleStateDriver.java:223)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:148)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.remove(ModuleStateDriver.java:104)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.remove(ScopedModuleDriver.java:236)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.remove(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:154)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.remove(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:157)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$4.previous(ModuleStateDriver.java:236)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$4.previous(ModuleStateDriver.java:223)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:148)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.remove(ModuleStateDriver.java:104)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.remove(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:191)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$3.previous(BaseDeployment.java:758)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:148)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.remove(BaseDeployment.java:323)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.remove(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.remove(DeploymentStateChecker.java:216)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.remove(AppContainerInvoker.java:135)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.silentRemove(AbstractOperation.java:451)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCancel(ActivateOperation.java:132)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.silentCancelOnPrepareFailure(AbstractOperation.java:423)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:101)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:229)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
>
```

EDIT3: I get the same error (duplicate persistance unit) when deploying the package prepared by eclipse (the one in .metadata directory) through weblogic console. This package differs from the one made by commandline maven by having all the sub-modules unpacked (exploded).

If you can shed any light on this issue, please help. Workarounds help also (maybe there is a way to link fastswapping with manually deployed exploded dir?)